# Abrir url con un boton desde un fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, url, botón, fragment

quisiera abrir una url con un botón que se encuentra alojado en un fragment,la idea es colocar un botón en cada fragment y que cada botón me lleve a una url distinta.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_id);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new InteligensaFragment()).commit();
}





@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

 private Button btn;
 private Uri url;

public void onClick(View v){
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.inteligensaurl:
            url=Uri.parse("https://www.inteligensa.com/");
            btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.inteligensaurl);
            btn.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
}
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    Fragment myfragment = null;
    boolean fragmentSeleccionado = false;
    String tittle ="";
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.background);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewt);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_id);

    if (id == R.id.nav_inteligensa) {
        myfragment = new InteligensaFragment();
        fragmentSeleccionado = true;
        tittle="INTELIGENSA";
        linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.material_design);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.web_hi_res_512);
        textView.setText("Inteligensa");
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_inteliseño) {
        myfragment = new InteliSenoFragment();
        fragmentSeleccionado = true;
        tittle="INTELISEÑO";
        linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.inteliseno);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.web_hi_res_512);
        textView.setText("Inteliseño");
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_intelitec) {
        myfragment = new InteliTecFragment();
        fragmentSeleccionado = true;
        tittle="INTELITEC";
        linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.intelitecfondo2);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo_intelitec);
        textView.setText("Intelitec");
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_intelifon) {
        myfragment = new InteliFoneFragment();
        fragmentSeleccionado = true;
        tittle="INTELIFON";
        textView.setText("InteliFon");
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_intelipunto) {
        myfragment = new InteliPuntoFragment();
        fragmentSeleccionado = true;
        tittle="INTELIPUNTO";
        textView.setText("InteliPunto");
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_intelisoft) {
        myfragment = new InteliSoftFragment();
        fragmentSeleccionado = true;
        tittle="INTELISOFT";
        textView.setText("InteliSoft");
    }

    if(fragmentSeleccionado==true){
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor, myfragment).commit();
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(tittle);

    }


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

Al momento de construir el evento onclick me crea salta este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Es incorrecto buscar la referencia de un elemento dentro del método onClick()

```
public void onClick(View v){
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.inteligensaurl:
            url=Uri.parse("https://www.inteligensa.com/");
            //btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.inteligensaurl);
            //btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}
```

La definición de esta referencia realizala dentro de onCreate()

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.inteligensaurl);
   btn.setOnClickListener(this);
   ...
   ...
```

**Editando...**

Comment: Estoy tratando te colocar el botón dentro de un fragment y no en un Activity, donde debería crear el código para que dicho botón funcione? en mi MainActivity.java o en mi InteligensaFragment.java?

Answer (score 0):

El error que te muestra es porque el elemento que agregaste es ImageButton no Button, Solo cambia la instancia a

```
Private ImageButton Btn;

Btn = findViewById(R.id.inteligensaurl)
```

---

**UPDATE**
Puedes utilizar la siguiente instrucción para hacer el listener del clic

```
Btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       switch (v.getId()){
           case R.id.inteligensaurl:
               url=Uri.parse("https://www.inteligensa.com/");
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: Gracias por la corrección, pero ahora cuando configuro el onClick en mi Image Button me aparece este mensaje 

"Corresponding method handler 'public void onClick(android.view.View)' not found  The onClick attribute value should be the name of a method in this View's context to invoke when the view is clicked. This name must correspond to a public method that takes exactly one parameter of type View.  Must be a string value, using '\;' to escape characters such as '\n' or '\uxxxx' for a unicode character.  Issue id: OnClick"

Comment: Puede ser la forma en la que esta declarada la función OnClick intenta utilizar el que actualice en la respuesta

Comment: No funciona, sera porque estoy trabajando desde un fragment y no desde un activity directamente?